# Move Button to be in the same line with Checkbox and Textbox Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to move the button to be in the same line as the checkbox and textbox. Currently it displays the elements as shown below...

[image]

What I want is to have something shown below...

[image]

Also, the textbox beside the checkbox fills up the whole space in its line. How can I make it shorter?

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <input type="checkbox"> Break After
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

<button id="btnextra" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md">Extra</button>
```

I have my jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e0j15brv/).

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap the `<button>` in `<span class="input-group-btn">`,
**update**: I added a wrapper `<div class="form-group row">` to contain the form elements also used `.col-xs-8` class to control the size, I really suggest using the standard classes and provided by bootstrap, here is a working snippet:

```css
.btnextra {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.form-group-centered {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br />
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group-centered">
      <div class="input-group pull-left" style="
      width: 300px;
  ">
          <span class="input-group-addon"> <input type="checkbox"> Break After </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">

      </div>
      <button id="btnextra" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btnextra pull-left" style="
  ">Extra</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I separate the textbox and the button? Also, the textbox still fills the whole remaining space. How can I make it smaller while keeping all elements at the center?

Comment: Glad to help, let me check it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ti3Cxrm the elements don't center :( How do I center it?

Comment: @chris_techno25, I fixed it, notice `.form-group-centered` CSS class that I added.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use `button` how suggest from @ROOT you can do that:

```css
.input-group {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="checkbox"> Break After
                </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

<button id="btnextra" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md">Extra</button>
```

add css class for `input-group`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  How can I make the textbox smaller while keeping all elements at the center? When I do your CSS width 50% it shortens the textbox but they're still separated by a big gap. Thank you.

Comment: If i run my code that 'Gap' doesn't exist, can you edit your code and post all code with that result?

Comment: I have tested your code in JSfiddle and it doesn't have a gap, but copy pasted it in my project and it leaves a gap. Weird. My project already contains thousands of lines of code, should I still post? I just copy pasted your code but it runs differently in my project.

Comment: Mmmh, can you see if is different css property of my snippet and your full code?

Comment: In my full code I don't have my own CSS. All CSS used are by bootstrap I just use the default ones.

Comment: You don't have any other plugin/framework have this class ?

Comment: Please see this screenshot... https://pasteboard.co/Jb36GnB.png

Comment: Also, I could be wrong but I don't see any reference that could be the problem... https://pasteboard.co/Jb37xGC.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215080/discussion-between-simone-rossaini-and-chris-techno25).